# No Drilldown for SonarQube Coverage Widget

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I'm using JaCoCo for coverage, and uploading the data with the SonarQube plugin for Jenkins.

I can see the jacoco.exec file, and when I import the contents using the EclEmma Eclipse plugin, I can see the highlighted line coverage.

However, in SonarQube, I am just getting a coverage % number, with no class drilldown.

[image: SonarQube Coverage Screenshot]

I can see the code when I look at Lines of Code, or Complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're code is 100% covered by your tests, so there's nothing to drilldown on. The drilldown only shows where you have problems, so if you're code is fully covered, it won't show anything.

Comment: Good to know. I am just setting it up for a new project and wrote some dummy tests to make sure the pipeline to SonarQube was working.